# How to get streamkey and rtmpURL for instagram live video?

Tags: live-streaming, instagram-graph-api, live-video

Currently, I'm using yellowdeck application to get streamkey and rtmpurl. So, instead of using yellowdeck, is it possible to get streamkey and rtmpurl using insatgram graph APIs ?